# ignore text between two Strings with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a text and I want to extract Parentheses of text with regex java.
for example of text:

```
<p>Now a days, regenerative medicine(1) in stem cell(3) filed
   widely <label>attractive(10) by</label> attractive by scientists(4).</p>
```

I want to extract Parentheses of text if Parentheses no exist between label tags.
for example of extract above text:

```
(1)
(3)
(4)
```

it should not extract parentheses between label tags.
i use of regex following :

```
 (<label>){0,1}[(\\w\\W)&&[^[</label>|\\(|\\)]]]*(\\(\\s*[(\\w\\W)&&[^\\(\\)]]+\\)) 
 [(\\w\\W)&&[^[</label>|\\(|\\)]]]*(</label>){0,1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = "<p>Now a days, regenerative medicine(1) in stem cell(3) filed widely <label>attractive(10) by</label> attractive by scientists(4).</p>".replaceAll("<label>.*</label>", "");;
        //String inin = in.replaceAll("<label>.*</label>", "");
        //System.out.println(inin);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("(" + m.group(1) + ")");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
(1)
(3)
(4)
```

I am just ignoring the text inside the label tag and then taking the text which is inside bracket.

Comment: it should not extract parentheses between label tags

Comment: `(10)` should not be there as it is between `<label>` tag

Comment: OK. I guess a clean approach would be to separate this into two steps: (A) remove the label elements with all its children and (B) extract the numbers. (B) can be done as described above. (A) can be done using SAX, XSLT, XQuery or some other XML processing mechanism.

Comment: @user986566 I edited my answer . I think this will solves your problem.